# Android - Facebook SDK App-scoped user id when getting friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm implementing an Android app where a user can choose to login via Facebook, and I'm working on a feature that will open up a Friend Picker so they can become friends within my app with people they are already friends with on Facebook.

I'm running into issues with these new app-scoped ids though. My problem is this:

When I log in using LoginManager like so:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
```

I get a LoginResult in which the userId is something like:

```
1020864xxxxxxxxxx
```

I get this for every user the first time they log in via Facebook, and I store that in a database along with their other account information.

Now, when I open up my friend picker and call

```
user/friends
```

All the users I get back have ids that are super long and look nothing like the user id I get when logging in.

So I have no way of knowing who these users are in my own app because I have no access to their actual userId that is in my database when they log in for the first time.

How is one to handle this?

Comment: You can not get all friends of a user any more via `/user/friends`, only those that are users of your app as well (and have granted it `user_friends` permission) – and for those of course you get the correct app-scoped ids. Are you sure that you not rather calling the `/user/invitable_friends`? That endpoint does not return user ids at all, but short-lived tokens only.

Comment: I'm not trying to get all, I'm just trying to get the actual user ids for friends that have used the app. Found out that me/friends works though.

Comment: They also have a mutual friends API which solves the exact same problem : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user.context/mutual_friends . Have you used it ?